# bool(input("Enter:") always returns True

Tags: python-3.x, boolean

You can also convert strings into Booleans as long as the strings contain either
True or False (and nothing else). For example:

```
status = bool(input('OK to proceed: '))
print(status)
print(type(status))
```

When we run this output:

```
OK to proceed: False
True
<class 'bool'>
```

It still returns True even if we input 0 or False. Why is that?

Comment: use `status = input('OK to proceed: ').lower() == "ok"` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other Python sequences, a string is truthy (so `bool(the_string)` is `True`), if it is non-empty. Only empty strings convert to `False`.

```
truthy = bool("any content")
falsey = bool("")
```

If you were reading a tutorial that suggested typing `False` at the prompt from `input()` would get you the Boolean value `False`, it may be that it was written for Python 2, where `input` did the equivalent of `eval(input())` in Python 3. That's not something you generally want, as it allows the user entering the text to run any Python code they can fit into an expression (including expressions with side effects like deleting all the files on your hard drive).

Comment: Makes sense, Thank You